# I'm after a reference for specific CLI instances

Tags: command-line

I've had a good search online but cannot find a reference for what certain commands do.

Specifically, I'm talking about when in the Terminal a minus/dash followed by a letter is used in a command.

Some of them I do know, like -h for human readable, -V for version etc.

As an example I cannot find anything that explains the -m in the following command:

**python3 -m venv my_env**

Also can anyone explain, does it matter where in the command the -m for example is placed? Could it be at the end or middle? And does -m always do the same or does that change depending on the command being entered?

Are they specific to Debian based distros?

If anyone has a reference they could point me too that would be great.

Comment: https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/python3.1.html

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Ubuntu maybe a Debian based distro, but your question isn't specifically on-topic as I read it*.

Comment: just FYI:  beyond `man` (which does require you to know the command before you can look up it's page), there are also other manual like tools.  `apropos` (eg. `apropos directory` can let you know `ls` is the command will display a directory, along with every other directory related tool), `info` & more...  (many commands will provide documentation with `--help` or `-h`  (--help for GNU commands, -h or equiv. if they're older unix commands from 70s & 80s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the manpages (the manual) with the `man` command.

This will give you a description of the command and details about how to use the command.

Example: `man grep`

Comment: How did I not know about this!? Awesome, thanks!